# VB.Net LINQ equivalent of SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I have inherited a database that I can't modify and need join/grouping results from the 2 tables (without any foreign key).

**Table A (Adjuster)**

```
Adjuster_Rec INT, 
Adjuster_Name VARCHAR(100), 
Adjuster_FK_Market_Rec INT,
Adjuster_Active BIT
```

**Table FD (Pre_FinanceDetail)**

```
MarketID INT,
MarketName VARCHAR(100)
```

**SQL**

```
Select A.Adjuster_Rec, A.Adjuster_Name, A.Adjuster_FK_Market_Rec, FD.MarketName
from Adjuster A
Left Join Pre_FinanceDetail FD ON A.Adjuster_FK_Market_Rec = FD.MarketID 
WHERE A.Adjuster_Active = 1
GROUP BY A.Adjuster_Rec, A.Adjuster_Name, A.Adjuster_FK_Market_Rec, FD.MarketName
```

What would be the VB.NET LINQ equivalent for this?

Comment: That `GROUP BY` is completely useless because there's no aggregate function so there's nothing to group.  Just search for how to perform a left outer join in LINQ.